# Dereferenced pointer assignments

Tags: c, pointers, casting

Consider the code snippet below:

```
int *p=NULL,*t=NULL,e;
char l=65;
char *k=&l;
p=(int*)&l;
t=(int*)k;
e=*t;
printf("%d\n",*p);
printf("%d\n",*t);
printf("%d\n",e);
```

The output of the above snippet is as follows:

```
16705
16705
65
```

Now it is evident that `&l` is an address to a char and `p=(int*)&l` lets an int pointer i.e p point to the same location this is the same with pointer t. Now if I dereference p rightly so it will try to dereference 4 consecutive memory blocks (assuming int points to 4 bytes) and print out a garbage value of sorts which happens for `*t` as well but when I print e I get 65 back which is confusing to me as `e=*t` which should be same as `*p` or `*t` perhaps?

Comment: Fixing your second statement in that paragraph, "Now if I dereference p... I'll invoke undefined behavior and can no longer draw any conclusions regarding the behavior of my code"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dereferencing `p` (i.e. using `*p`) is undefined behavior as there isn't an `int` at that location. Anything may happen... and no one can explain the output you get.

Compiling your code with "gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic ..." gives me:

```
main.cpp:19:1: warning: array subscript 'int[0]' is partly outside array bounds of 'char[1]' [-Warray-bounds]
   19 | printf("%x\n",*p);
```

which directly tells you that the program has problems that needs to be fixed.

Comment: So this goes on to say that e=*t is undefined and that getting the same value back as l (65) is not what is expected?

Comment: @lava_07 That's not what I wrote. Your `p` is a pointer-to-int but (using a cast) you force it to point to a `char`. Then you read the value by dereferencing `p`. That's undefined behavior so from there anything may happen.

Comment: @lava_07 ... but yes `e=*t;` has the same problem. It all boils down to reading a location of a char-type object as if it's an int-type object.